# Python - check if arg from arparse was chosen

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I would like to check if argument from argsparse was chosen, if not I would like to choose random value for that variable.

Here is example:

```
parser.add_argument('--tempo', default=120, type=int, help='Tempo of the track')
```

and one way to do that is for example:

```
args = parser.parse_args()    
if args.tempo==120: #my default int
    tempo=random.randint(60,350)
```

But that way when user would like to call my program with for example: `main.py --tempo 120`, it will also choose random value. How can I check if argument was chosen or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the test.
if a user chose 120 then it will give a random number.
I think the best it to remove the default and check if it is empty.

```
parser.add_argument('--tempo', default=None, type=int, help='Tempo of the track')
args = parser.parse_args()    
if args.tempo==None: #my default int
    args.tempo=randint(60,350)
```

Comment: `args.tempo is None` is the most reliable test.